# Tkinter Rotated Resizing Cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I was working with using Tkinter Cursors and I found this list of all the cursors it offers: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/cursors.html

Now I was interested in these:

[image]

These cursors are the ones that show up when you are resizing a window - but there are a few missing. When you resize a window in both directions (width & height), you get a 45 deg rotated arrow cursor which isn't part of this list...

So, does Tkinter offer that cursor? is there a way I can add that cursor and use it?

Comment: Why don't you use those 'xxxx_xxxx_corner' cursors?

Comment: If I don't have any other choice, I would probably go with those. But they aren't the ones Im looking for. They not only have the arrow, but also 2 lines around them and are entirely different from the sb cursor set.

Comment: If your platform is Windows, try `size_nw_se` or `size_ne_sw`.  See [document](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/cursors.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes:

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(window, bg='red', width=50, height=20,cursor='size_ne_sw').pack(expand=True, fill='both')


window.mainloop()
```

see [details](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/cursors.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I had been searching for a list of cursors and the other website was the closest I found. will use this now :)